# modifying values in pointers is very slow?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, optimization

I'm working with a huge amount of data stored in an array, and am trying to optimize the amount of time it takes to access and modify it. I'm using Window, c++ and VS2015 (Release mode).

I ran some tests and don't really understand the results I'm getting, so I would love some help optimizing my code.

First, let's say I have the following class:

```
class foo
{
public:
    int x;

    foo() 
    {
        x = 0;
    }

    void inc()
    {
        x++;
    }

    int X()
    {
        return x;
    }

    void addX(int &_x)
    {
        _x++;
    }

};
```

I start by initializing 10 million pointers to instances of that class into a std::vector of the same size.

```
#include <vector>
int count = 10000000;
std::vector<foo*> fooArr;
fooArr.resize(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
     fooArr[i] = new foo();
}
```

When I run the following code, and profile the amount of time it takes to complete, it takes approximately 350ms (which, for my purposes, is far too slow):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    fooArr[i]->inc(); //increment all elements
}
```

To test how long it takes to increment an integer that many times, I tried:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    x++;
}
```

Which returns in <1ms.

I thought maybe the number of integers being changed was the problem, but the following code still takes 250ms, so I don't think it's that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    fooArr[0]->inc(); //only increment first element
}
```

I thought maybe the array index access itself was the bottleneck, but the following code takes <1ms to complete:

```
int x;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    x = fooArr[i]->X(); //set x
}
```

I thought maybe the compiler was doing some hidden optimizations on the loop itself for the last example (since the value of x will be the same during each iteration of the loop, so maybe the compiler skips unnecessary iterations?). So I tried the following, and it takes 350ms to complete:

```
int x;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    fooArr[i]->addX(x); //increment x inside foo function
}
```

So that one was slow again, but maybe only because I'm incrementing an integer with a pointer again.

I tried the following too, and it returns in 350ms as well:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    fooArr[i]->x++;
}
```

So am I stuck here? Is ~350ms the absolute fastest that I can increment an integer, inside of 10million pointers in a vector? Or am I missing some obvious thing? I experimented with multithreading (giving each thread a different chunk of the array to increment) and that actually took longer once I started using enough threads. Maybe that was due to some other obvious thing I'm missing, so for now I'd like to stay away from multithreading to keep things simple.

I'm open to trying containers other than a vector too, if it speeds things up, but whatever container I end up using, I need to be able to easily resize it, remove elements, etc.

I'm fairly new to c++ so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should take a look at the assembly code, to see what optimizations it's doing in each case. The version with `x = fooArr[i]->X();` is probably optimizing out the whole loop, and just doing `x = fooArr[n-1]->X();`

Comment: That plain integer incrementing test is very suspicious, that's very likely to be optimized to something trivial. Anyway, why aren't the foos just in the vector directly, without a pointer?

Comment: @harold In my application the elements equivalent to the foos in my examples get passed around (in whole and in part) to a lot of different arrays...so it made sense to me to just pass around the pointers. Do you foresee a speed up if I store them directly, or store by reference or something?

Comment: I think you just need to turn the optimisation level up. Simple functions should be inlined, then resolved to a couple of machine instructions, if all they are doing is to increment a variable.

Comment: @Tyson certainly in this example, storing them value should be faster. But if your actual program is different in a significant way, such conclusions do not transfer over to it. It may be best, therefore, to instead construct a *representative* example

Comment: I can easily categorize your speeds here: The slow ones write to 38Mb of memory, and the fast ones write to 4 bytes of memory.  The problem is the _cache_

Comment: @MooingDuck except for this case: `fooArr[0]->inc();`

Comment: your simple increment loop will be replaced by x= 10000000 by any decent compiler

Comment: @harold Thanks, I think I'll refactor things to use values instead of pointers. I'm getting ~4x speed boost when doing that in my tests above.

Comment: BTW, your 350ms main test = 35 nano seconds per loop. Easily maps to one cache miss back to RAM every 100 or so loops

Comment: @pm100: Sounds like a OS context switch to me.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look from the CPU point of view.

Incrementing an integer means I have it in a CPU register and just increments it. This is the fastest option.

I'm given an address (vector->member) and I must copy it to a register, increment, and copy the result back to the address. Worst: My CPU cache is filled with vector pointers, not with vector-member pointers. Too few hits, too much cache "refueling".

If I could manage to have all those members just in a vector, CPU cache hits would be much more frequent.

Comment: Do note that the integer increment loop may have but optimized away by the compiler.  We really need to see how the OP bench marked the code and what settings they used to know for sure what is going on.

Comment: @NathanOliver My benchmark is nothing fancy. Literally just a "GetTickCount()" before and after the loops, and then I subtract the first from the second to get milliseconds elapsed.

Comment: @Tyson That leads me to believe the compiler optimized your for loop away since it has no side effects.  To know for sure change `int x = 0;` to `volatile int x = 0;` and see if the time changes.

Comment: @NathanOliver with "volatile" added, the loop now takes 250ms, so you seem to be correct.

Comment: @Tyson OK.  So there you go.  The compiler is really good at avoiding things it feels it doesn't need to do which makes micro bench-marking difficult.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yea I wondered if something fishy was going on. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
int count = 10000000;
std::vector<foo> fooArr;
fooArr.resize(count, foo());

for (auto it= fooArr.begin(); it != fooArr.end(); ++it) {
   it->inc();
}
```

The `new` is killing you and actually you don't need it because `resize` inserts elements at the end if the size it's greater (check the docs: [std::vector::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/))

And the other thing it's about using pointers which **IMHO** should be avoided until the last moment and it's uneccesary in this case. The performance should be a little bit faster in this case since you get better locality of your references (see cache locality). If they were polymorphic or something more complicated it might be different.

Comment: I don't think he includes the instantiation in his benchmark, so the `new` is not included in the number. It is a question of optimization of the simple loop, that breaks the comparison.

Comment: The creation of the array (ie, all the "new"s) was excluded from my benchmark times, but storing values instead of pointers definitely offers a good speedup. I get 100ms now when using your code, and 80ms when iterating the loop using regular indices. I think the solution for me is to ultimately refactor my code to use values and references to those values, instead of pointers. Thanks!

Comment: @TommyAndersen Yes you're both right, I didn't read it fully!. I'll update my answer.